# How to play a tone using an audiobuffer with Tone.Player?

Tags: javascript, audio, tone.js

Using Tone.js I'm able to play a sound using the following code

```
var player = new Tone.Player("./sounds/snare_drum.wav").toMaster();
player.autostart = true;
```

However when I try to do the same thing with an audiobuffer nothing happens.

```
var player = new Tone.Player(buffers[i]).toMaster();
player.autostart = true;
console.log(buffers[i]);
```

The console.log confirms there is an AudioBuffer

```
AudioBuffer { sampleRate: 44100, length: 83771, duration: 1.8995691609977323, numberOfChannels: 1 }
```

According to the [documentation](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/13.8.25/Player) it should be able to take an url or an AudioBuffer.
What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation

```js
player.autostart = true;
```

starts the playback as soon as the file or buffer is loaded.  Probably if the loading is already complete when you set the flag, then it is ignored and the playback is not started automatically.  Since the AudioBuffer is almost certainly already loaded in memory, this could be the reason why the playback doesn't start.

You can add a test to check the status of the audio stream: if it's not already loaded, then you set `autostart` to true and delay the start (to avoid starting a stream not yet loaded).  If the audio stream is already loaded then you can safely start it manually.

```js
if (!player.loaded)
    player.autostart = true;
else
    player.start();
```

I have done a quick test both with a WAV file and with an AudioBuffer cases and it seems to work.  Not sure if this is the best solution though.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Tone.js documentation that shows how this is done, very similar to what @William-Spinelli has suggested in his answer:

```
var player = new Tone.Player(buffers[i]).toMaster();

Tone.loaded().then(() => {
    player.start();
});
```